# Paperclip: "is not recognized by the 'identify' command"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I've found a couple of other related questions but none of the answers are working for me as I'm using a Windows machine to develop.

Everything is configured and setup correctly as far as I know and right now the only problem I'm getting is the following: https://i.stack.imgur.com/phYTX.png

Seeing that I'm a windows user, I've installed ImageMagick and ran the `which identify` command to give me the identify path to place in my development.rb:
`Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/c/Program Files/ImageMagick-6.7.1-Q16/identify"`

Anyone have an idea why I am getting this error still?

**EDIT:** Might the fact that my file variable is called `photo_1` have anything to do with it? Should I just use `photo` instead?

Comment: Could you explain to me how I would do this via the command line?

Comment: `c:/1.jpg JPEG 1680x1050 1680x1050+0+0 8-bit DirectClass 221KB 0.000u 0:00.002`

Comment: That command path looks very wrong try Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "c:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.7.1-Q16\identify"

Comment: I still get the same error after changing it :/

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem is the command path.

Contrary to what you did, it should point to a folder not a precise binary.

Try:

```
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "c:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.7.1-Q16\"
```

Comment: Still doesn't work. Here's the error the rails server window terminal produces: `'C:/Users/JP/AppData/Local/Temp/stream20110724-2976-1te5two.jpg[0]' 2>/dev/null
[paperclip] An error was received while processing: #<Paperclip::NotIdentifiedBy
ImageMagickError: C:/Users/JP/AppData/Local/Temp/stream20110724-2976-1te5two.jpg
 is not recognized by the 'identify' command.>`

Answer (score 0):

This is the only solution which saved my day after trying all the above and a lot more
[Image file is not recognized by the 'identify' command. (heroku)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12750737/image-file-is-not-recognized-by-the-identify-command-heroku)