# Image file is not recognized by the 'identify' command. (heroku)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3, imagemagick, paperclip

I'm trying to have Paperclip working with Heroku and Amazon S3.

Everything works fine on localhost (mac OS and Amazon), but when I'm deploying to heroku and trying the feature, I have this error :

```
2 errors prohibited this area from being saved:
Asset /tmp/paris20121005-2-2cwxgx.jpg is not recognized by the 'identify' command.
Asset /tmp/paris20121005-2-2cwxgx.jpg is not recognized by the 'identify' command.
```

It works when I remove the :styles => { } option in my model, but the file isn't processed (I need different image sizes).

I also have the rmagick gem in my gemfile.

Here is my gemfile (only the paperclip part) :

```
gem "paperclip"
gem "rmagick", :require => 'RMagick'
gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 1.3.4'
```

I don't have Paperclip.options[:command_path] set in my environment.rb or production.rb so no problem on this side.

Here is my model :

```
class Area < ActiveRecord::Base
  require 'RMagick'
  has_attached_file :asset, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "180x190>" },
       :storage => :s3,
       :s3_credentials => "#{::Rails.root.to_s}/config/s3.yml",
       :url => :s3_domain_url.to_s,
       :path => "/:style/:id/:filename"
end
```

Any clue on that ? I've crawled every topics about it and nothing seems to work...

Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Apparently the new update to Cocaine gem (0.4.0) breaks the file names for Paperclip and ImageMagick. try rolling back to the previous version (0.3.2), it worked for me.

See here:

https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/1038

PS I believe RMagick is no longer needed on Heroku, works fine for me without it

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Changing the Cocain version to 0.3.2 worked great for me ! And yeah I deleted RMagick it wasn't needed.

Comment: HI @Itai Leibowitz, I got the same problem , however, i didnt include the cocaine gem in my application. at least i cant see it in my gemfile. Could you please tell how can i do it on heroku ? thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Heroku includes it automatically on their end - you should just add it to your gemfile like the following:

gem 'cocaine', '0.3.2'

PS check the original link I posted - there seem to have been updates to paperclip/cocaine to solve this already.

Comment: Thanks. I was pulling my hair out over this. Didn't realize this gem was included in my bundle. I had a much earlier version (0.1.x) in my Gemfile.lock, and didn't realize it.

Comment: This has been resolved in 2.8.0 and several other of the latest versions of paperclip.